# Can't access IIS domain name

Tags: asp.net, iis, publish

i am trying to publish my website in IIS but when i try to ping the domain name it will give this instead of local host

[image]

This how i created the site

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use a domain you don't own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datingapp.com domain is mapped to IP 72.52.4.119 which you can confirm using this [link](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3Adatingapp.com&run=toolpage)

If you want to point datingapp.com domain to your localhost, you need to add an entry in host file which can be found at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` on Windows operation system.

Open host file using any text editor in administrator mode and add the following:

127.0.0.1 datingapp.com

Comment: so everytime i want to create new domain name i should modify host file ?

Comment: I am not sure why you need domain name to browse your WebApp on localhost? Domain names are normally bound to server IP address which hosts your deployed application. If you still want to test your application using a domain name pointing to your local application then you will require a new entry in host file

Comment: i did what you said but i received  this error Handler "aspNetCore" has a bad module "AspNetCoreModuleV2" in its module list

Comment: @JamesFallon It means your original issue is resolved that `datingapp.com` is pointing to local website. Now you need to check on the documentation about hosting ASP.NET Core using IIS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: try and see if you can reach it from your mobile phone... that way you can see if it's a dns issue or just something on your machine... also just try and go to localhost and see if it loads like that...

If you are hosting more than one website on your local machine try turning everything off except for the one you need to validate....